# Change Data Capture: Invalid object name 'sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn' and 'sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to be a good SQL citizen  and **not** use the CDC tables directly, and use the [TVFs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510627(v=sql.105).aspx), it fails miserably for me.(SQL 2012 Enterprise SP3), following the pattern..

```
DECLARE @from_lsn binary(10), @to_lsn binary(10)
SET @from_lsn =
   sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('mytable')
SET @to_lsn   = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()
SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_mytable
  (@from_lsn, @to_lsn, N'mytable');
GO
```

I got the error

> Invalid object name 'cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_mytable'.

I then discovered I needed to put the schema infront of the table name on the function, but then got this:

> An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or
>   function cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_ ... .

So I tried to debug the lsn values to see if they were NULL/zero, as other posts encountered this issue but then discovered these functions didn't exist.

[image]

As you can see I can find these functions myself in the master db. Anyone know what I've done wrong?

I saw this [Microsoft connect article](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/765206/missing-cdc-system-function) where someone experienced the same issue, and their resolution is untenable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those functions do not return tables, they are scalar; so use variables.

```
DECLARE @from_lsn binary(10)
SET @from_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn(N'schema_table')
SELECT @from_lsn
```

You've also changed the code from the TechNet article, replace the third parameter in the final TVF to be `N'all'`:

```
DECLARE @from_lsn binary(10), @to_lsn binary(10)
SET @from_lsn = sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn(N'schema_table')
SET @to_lsn   = sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn()
SELECT @from_lsn,@to_lsn 
SELECT * FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_schema_table(@from_lsn, @to_lsn, N'all');
GO
```

The filter options are not your capture instance names or table names.
They are:

```
cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_capture_instance ( from_lsn , to_lsn , '<row_filter_option>' )  

<row_filter_option> ::=  
{ all  
 | all update old  
}
```

See [cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_capture_instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510627.aspx)

Note: If you've used a specific `capture_instance` name when enabling CDC for a table, use that wherever the word `capture_instance` appears in MSDN documentation as parameters. If you haven't used a `capture_instance` name, then it's likely to be `schema_table` e.g. `dbo_mytable`.